# What are the advantages of L2-SVM?

Tags: svm

I don't clearly understand about the advantages of L2-SVM compared with L1-SVM. The effect of L2-SVM is better than L1-SVM. I don't understand it. I want to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> L2-SVM is differentiable and imposes a bigger (quadratic vs. linear) loss for points which violate the margin.

From http://deeplearning.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/dlsvm.pdf